# Does TransactionScope really need the "Distributed Transaction Coordinator" service running?

Tags: sql-server, transactions, transactionscope

I am trying to understand the details of TransactionScope.
Below is quoted from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833153%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> Some procedures in this topic use types in the System.Transactions
>   assembly. Before you follow these procedures, you must make sure that
>   the **Distributed Transaction Coordinator service is running** on the
>   computer where you run the unit tests. Otherwise, the tests fail, and
>   the following error message appears: "Test method
>   ProjectName.TestName.MethodName threw exception:
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: MSDTC on server 'ComputerName' is
>   unavailable".

But strange enough, I stopped that service, and did some DB deletion within a TransactionScope, and didn't call the Complete() method at the end, which means the transaction should rollback.

The DB is not affected indeed. It seems the transaction still works well.

As I understand, we need **resource manager** (RM) and **transaction manager** (TM) to make the transaction on resources happen. In my scenario, the Distributed Transaction coordinator service is stopped, who is the transaction manager then?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you use `TransactionScope`, you are working with an [ambient transaction](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/florinlazar/archive/2005/04/19/409570.aspx), and the transaction is independently managed within your code.

The [TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class is defined by msdn as:

> Makes a code block transactional. This class cannot be inherited.
>
> ...
>
> Upon instantiating a TransactionScope by the new statement, the
>   transaction manager determines which transaction to participate in.
>   Once determined, the scope always participates in that transaction.
>   The decision is based on two factors: whether an ambient transaction
>   is present and the value of the TransactionScopeOption parameter in
>   the constructor. The ambient transaction is the transaction your code
>   executes in. You can obtain a reference to the ambient transaction by
>   calling the static Current property of the Transaction class.

Also from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172152%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The TransactionScope class provides a simple way to mark a block of
>   code as participating in a transaction, without requiring you to
>   interact with the transaction itself. A transaction scope can select
>   and manage the ambient transaction automatically.

Also from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172152%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> A TransactionScope object has three options:
>
> - Join the ambient transaction, or create a new one if one does not exist.
> - Be a new root scope, that is, start a new transaction and have that transaction be the new ambient transaction inside its own scope.
> - Not take part in a transaction at all. There is no ambient transaction as a result.

Answer (score 0):

The DTC service is only needed when the transaction is escalated. See more on this here: [Transaction Management Escalation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229978.aspx)

Escalation can be difficult to determine beforehand as by design, this is pretty automatic wich is cool but sometimes unexpected. But, basically, if you're running a transaction on a single SQL Server (not SQL 2000 I believe you need SQL 2005 at least or escalation always happens, see this link: [TransactionScope: transaction escalation behavior](http://pieterderycke.wordpress.com/2012/01/22/transactionscope-transaction-escalation-behavior/)) instance (one "Resource Manager" / RM), there are good chances that escalation will be avoided. And in general, it's a good thing because it can be costy in terms of performance.